# Applying filter on some attributes in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to classify some data for a project using Weka. So I need use logarithmic transformation on a single attribute by y=ln(x+1). I use MathExpression filter and my expression is log(A+1). I want my filter to apply only on a single attribute, however it applies on all attributes. How can i apply filter only single attribute.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the Weka GUI?

Comment: Yes I am using the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the attributes to act on by filling in "ignore range" with a comma separated list of attribute indices.

> ignoreRange -- Specify range of attributes to act on. This is a comma
>   separated list of attribute indices, with "first" and "last" valid
>   values. Specify an inclusive range with "-". E.g:
>   "first-3,5,6-10,last".

This information can be found by clicking the "More" button in the GenericObjectEditor (example shown below).

[image]